# Compare with a value and sort in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table like below

```
userid  zip
3       1000
4       1001
5       1002
6       1003
```

I want to show users nearby the login users. Consider one of the login user's userid is 5, I want to show the results like below. ie showing userid other than the login user's userid and sort the nearest zipcode first.

```
userid  zip
6       1003
4       1001
3       1000
```

Comment: `ORDER BY zip DESC` ?

Comment: what if there are thousand entries in the table and you choose some user whose zip code is nearly at the middle of the table ?

Comment: you should spending time on **sort the nearest zipcode** sorting zip numeric will e.g. in Germany not realy work

Comment: ORDER BY ZIP DESC gives the result 1000,1001,1003. But i want the result 1003,1001,1000 because 1003 is near 1002

Comment: `1002 - 1001 = 1` and `1003-1002 = 1` how will you decide `1003` is near to `1002` than `1001` ?

Comment: Actually i want to show the users near my zipcode..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your zip stays the same, just substring to return those with a final character +/- 1/2/3 from your postcode

`where zipcode != 'yourzip' AND zipcode like ('xxx%')`

would return many similar, you could then add a column where you do zipcode-yourzip and order by this field. so you'd get some proximity information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
select usersid,zip from users_location(name of your table )where userid!=(your user id) order by ZIP DESC
```